# Design a separate static parser class, which has access to the main class fields

Tags: c#, oop

I have run into the following problem when trying to implement a simple spreadsheet program in C#.

What I am trying to do is to have a `Table` class which basically is an array of objects of class `Cell`. However I would like to implement a separate `Parser` class which would accept all user input. Yet the methods of the `Parser` class need to have access to table's cells. And I am not sure how that should be implemented.

Perhaps better explained by code:

```
class Cell
{
  //fields
}

class Table
{
  private Cell[,] cells;
  public Cell At(int key);
}

static class Parser
{
  public static Cell GetCellReference(string userInput)
  {
    //somehow
    //return Table.At(parsedUserInput)
  }
}
```

One way I see of achieving that is by instantiating a `Table` object inside `Parser`, but that clearly defeats the purpose of the parser class itself. Another way I see is by passing a `Table` object to `Parser`'s methods, but that doesn't seem reasonable as the intent is to work with only one `Table` instance. Inheritance does not seem to apply between the parser and the table and so I find myself stuck. How should I change/modify the design to achieve the goal without violating basic principles of OOP?

Comment: `as the intent is to work with only one Table instance`. This means you are expecting to use [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and access the instance like `Table.Instance`. Can't tell if that is the right choice though - since that needs more information about your system.

Comment: write the parser to take in instance of Table. Dont hard wire yourself to there only being one; you might need to change you mind later (have > 1 'spreadsheet' active at once for example)

Comment: @pm100 Okay, I see a point in that. But what if I certainly had only one instance, e.g. if I used the singleton pattern, as suggested by @Vikhram?

Comment: it is simpler to just pass in the Table instance into the Parser constructor (or its methods) YOu seem to think this means that you have more than one instance, this is not so

Comment: @IliaZaichuk Follow good design principles for the sake of learning to program. Don't think "what's the worst design that I can *probably* get away with, if I'm lucky?" Think, "what's the best design that isn't overkill for this case?". On the other hand, doing the former is a great way to learn why you should do the latter instead.

Comment: I think now I see why my previous comment was not a good one, there is no good reason to believe that we might have a single instance of not-singleton class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have

```
public class Parser
{
   public Parser(Table table){..}
  public ReturnType DoIt(....) {...}
}
```

and then

```
var parser = new Parser(myTable);
var res = parser.DoIt(widgetWoo, bar33);
```

if you want PArser to be static then do

```
public static class Parser
{
   public ReturnType Parse(Table table,.....){..}
}
```

and then

```
var res = Parser.Parse(myTable, widgetWoo, bar33);
```

However it feels to me that Parser will have a lot of internal state. Better to be non-static

Comment: I see, many tables, many parsers. That does seem like a good solution. Use of singleton answers the question more directly, but I think I will go with this one. Thanks.